# Mouse over effect on touchscreen

Tags: mouseover, touchscreen, tablet

Obviously you dont have a mouse over effect on a touchscreen, but I would like some effect, maybe onclick? Does anybody have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the touchscreen I'm working with right now, the mouse over is a persistent effect of clicks. In other words, it's as if after clicking an item with an actual mouse and releasing the button, one never moved the mouse pointer afterwards.